# Reading a pixel value of a image

Tags: opencv

How can I read a pixel value of grayscale CV_8U image in open cv in c++? 
I've tried this code:

```
srcimg=imread("/home/bindu/gesture recognition/processed image/paddedimage/P1/G8/6.jpg");

cvtColor(srcimg, img, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cout<<grayimg.depth();
cout<<grayimg.channels();
imshow("image",srcimg);
for(i=0;i<img.rows;i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<img.cols;j++)
  {
   cout<<" "<<img.at<uchar>(Point(i,j));
  }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with your code - do you get an error?

Comment: You should use Point(j,i) instead of Point(i,j). See http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-at

Comment: Use either img.at<uchar>(Point(j,i )) or img.at<uchar>(i,j). This is: img.at<uchar>(Point(x,y)) or img.at<uchar>(row, column)